# Jquery animate() to slide from right to left

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-animate, slideshow

We have an application which is implemented with slide up animation already. But, now we want to change that to slide right animation. We want to display a slideshow like display for the content. What all i need to change in the existing code, to do so?

```
function gallery() {
    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery a.show') ? $('#gallery a.show') : $('#gallery a:first'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption')) ?
        $('#gallery a:first') : current.next()) : $('#gallery a:first'));

    //Get next image caption
    var caption = next.find('img').attr('rel');

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    })
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000)
    .removeClass('show');

    //Set the opacity to 0 and height to 1px
    $('#gallery .caption').animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 0            
    }).animate({
        height: '1px'           
    }, {
        queue: true,
        duration: 300
    });

    //Animate the caption, opacity to 0.7 and heigth to 100px, a slide up effect
    $('#gallery .caption').animate({
        opacity: 0.7
    }, 100).animate({
==>     height: '20px' 
    }, 500);

    //Display the content
    $('#gallery .content').html(caption);
}
```

This code, slides up the content. I tried placing,

```
right: '700px', in the line marked with ==>
```

In that case, it appeared like, the second content alone came from right to left.
Any help is greatly meant.

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, the code is broken, due to the ==> symbol. Pardon me.

Comment: It would be better if you could remove unnecessary parts of code from here. Giving example HTML markup or setting up a fiddle, may help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you please display your html markup as well? Or even better - create a jsFiddle of its current behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In line 42 try replacing the line  `height: '1px'`  with `width: '1px'`. Just a thought, cant guarantee it will work.

Comment: It worked when i replace, height: '1px' with width: '1px' and width: '500px' in the line next to right:'700px'.